# Save filled form data in Django if user is not logged in?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I search Django-way to do some non tipical feature (I think). My env is Django 2.0.2, PostgreSQL 9.6 and Python 3.6.4. So, I have model and form like:

```
# ./app/models.py

from users.models import User # custom user model

class SubscribeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=80)

# ./app/forms.py

class SubscribeForm(forms.Form):
    phone = forms.EmailField(label='Phone Number', max_length=100)
```

Also, my view for this model like:

```
# ./app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from users.models import User

class SubscribeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    template_name = 'app/subscribe.html'
    form_class = SubscribeForm

    def post(self, request):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'client': user, 'form': form})
```

Would be great to understand what to do that logic after save form:

1. Anonymous user fill the form and click `Save`;
2. He is redirecting to `login` page (because `LoginRequiredMixin`);
3. After enter to the site, all data which he filled — saved to his account (automatically).

> This feature we can see when online shopping: we choose goods, add to
>   our cart and only later, site ask us for login to site, if we are not (for save our order).

I think, my question solve saving data to `request.session` and re-save to DB after logged in, but I have no idea how to do that on my code and is this correctly? I am newbie in Django... yet!

Comment: Isn't just easier to redirect the user on attempt to get into the `SubscribeView` to the `login` page and then let him fill in this form and submit it? Is it really necessary to do it this way? If it is, then you could try to save the object in the request.session and later after the login look into the session if there is any object you want to save, then save and do some stuff or render the form to fill in.

Comment: @Krystofee unfortunately this is my task. Main idea is try to understand how to make non specific feature with Django-way. Prototype of this task is online shop, who doesn't ask anonymous user to login when his put goods to the shopping cart, only when checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using `request.session` to store the data without saving it to the database is one approach, you can eighter save it to the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` if you are developing mainly javascript AJAX frontent. But if you render every view with django then is using `request.session` better for you. Consider storing ids of the objects in the `request.session` in array and then use it as you want, remember to seralize it to JSON (`json.dumps(list of ids)`) before assigning it to the `request.session`.

Comment: Could you please share some example code for more understanding what you mean at this answer? Thanks.

Comment: @VicShóstak Oh sure, I'll update my answer and let you now in a while.